# Why Doesn't .container Also Change Headings to Black and White in @media print{}

Tags: html, css, css-selectors, media-queries

Just curious, why when I do print preview the headings are still colored after I've set a class selector to black? If by putting .container within the media rule and setting the color too black, should every text including headings be set to black? I know I can easily add h1, h2... I'm just curious as to why I can not set a selector to a specific color and everything within that selector be set to that during print? Thanks for the feedback!

```
    /* reset style */
    html {
      font-size: 12px;
    }

    /* body and page container */
    .container {
      max-width: 600px;
      margin: 0 auto;
      border: 3px red;
    }

    /* headings */
    header {
      text-align: center;
      padding: .4em;
      background-color: darkgrey;
    }

    h1 {
      text-shadow:2px -4px 5px black;
      color: #EADCDC;
      font-size: 5em;
      

    }

    h2 {
      color: brown;
      font-size: 3em;
    }

    p {
      font-size: 1.2em;
      line-height: 1.4em;

    }

    body {
      font-family: Tahoma, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
      background-color: #dee9f9;
      
    }

    h3 {
      color: green;
      font-size: 2em;
    }

    article {
      background-color: gold;
      padding: 3%;
    }


    .accent {
        text-decoration: underline;
        text-align: center;
        line-height: .8em;
    }

    /* unordered list */
    ul {
      list-style: circle;
      font-size: 1.2em;
      line-height: 1.4em;
    }

    aside {
      background-color: #EADCDC;
      width: 45%;
      padding: 2%;
      margin: 2%;
      box-shadow: 3px 3px 3px black;
      border-radius: 30px;
      float: right;
      line-height:4em;
    }

    footer {
      padding: 0.6em;
      color: ivory;
      background-color: darkgrey;
      text-align: center;
    }
    /// This is what I am referring to 
    @media print {
      body, .container, aside, article {
        color: black;
        background-color: white;
        box-shadow: none;
      }
    }
    @page {
      margin: 1in;
    }
```

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
   <html lang="en">
      <head>
         <title>Battle</title>
         <meta charset = "utf-8">
         <meta name = "viewport" content = "width=device-width">
         <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Bree+Serif&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
         <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
      </head>
      <body>
         <div class="container">
            <header>
               <h1>Super Battle</h1>
            </header>
            <aside>
               <h2 class="accent"> ARE YOU READY?</h2>
               <h3>DATE</h3>
               <p>10/31/2022</p>
               <p>12AM - 12pm</p>
               <h3>LOCATION</h3>
               <p>LAS VEGAS</p>
               <p>NEVADA</p>
               <p>MGM GRAND CASINO</p>
            </aside>
            <article>
               <h3>PRICES</h3>
               <p>$200General</p>
               <p>$400 VIP</p>
               <p>$1000 ALL ACCESS</p>
               <h3>SPONSORS</h3>
               <ul>
                  <li>ELON MUSK</li>
                  <li>DONALD TRUMP</li>
                  <li>TEKASHI 69</li>
                  <li>BARACK OBAMAS X WIFE</li>
               </ul>
            </article>
            <footer>
               <p> www.LASVEGASBATTLE.us</p>
            </footer>
         </div>
      </body>
   </html>
```

Comment: Could you add a runnable snippet to your question which shows the problem. I cannot reproduce the issue and that's possibly because I have misinterpreted what your HTML structure is. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: You've still got h1, h2, and so on setting color